# How to create environment on 3D games without game engine?

Tags: 3d, game-engine

In Unity, for example, comes with an editor to places model to your liking. But what if you aren't using any game engine and written from OpenGL or something? You must write an environment editor? Is there any tools to places model and export coordinate data or something?

Comment: -1 I'm a game developer, and i'm absolutly sure that you find information about this topic at google. And of course: This question is not very useful because the most ppl don't write their own engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @starbeamrainbowlabs says, you can use a separate application, such as Blender, 3ds Max, or Maya, to model objects and terrain.

If you're writing your game engine from scratch, starting with OpenGL and nothing else, you will need to either write or link to a library that can read one of the 3D data formats that your modeling application can write.

Any existing model-loading library will probably have its own idea of how to represent the loaded model.  This can be bad (because you have to use their modeling framework or translate it to your own), or it can be good (because you get to use their modeling framework and don't have to write your own).

Answer (score 1):

blender can export to a number of different formats, but I do not know whether any of them will be useful though. To export, go to File -> Export to see the list of types that it can export to. There will probably be a plugin written by a member of the blender community that will do what you want if you can't find the functionality built in.

blender: http://blender.org